# How to get total number of pages per chapter (at the chapter heading)

Tags: counters

I am writing a thesis and I want to track how many pages I'm aiming for per chapter. At the moment I have a rough (non-functional) macro for this which I put below the chapter heading.

How can I get the number of pages in a chapter?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% The magic counter would go where ??? is
\newcommand\pagesexpected[1]{??? of #1 pages written}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\pagesexpected{3}

\end{document}
```

[image: example MWE]

(I am personally a huge fan of LuaLaTeX, so use of Lua is definitely encouraged, but any help is appreciated/can be ported to Lua later.)

Comment: So what is the number of pages then? Shouldn't `3` be replaced by `#1` rather?

Comment: Yes sorry, fixed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `page` counter is a very unreliable friend. It could be tracked only roughly with `xcntperchap` which has a `\RegisterTrackCounter` macro that defines `page` to be tracked by `chapter` (as specified), i.e. stores the number of pages per chapter.

Please note that basically any counter other than `page`  works pretty well with `xcntperchap` and `xassoccnt`.

The macro `\ObtainTrackedValue{chapter}{page}` will retrieve the number of pages of the current chapter, but it might fail if there's an empty page as in many cases with `\cleardoublepage` etc.

This needs the recent `xassoccnt` v1.4 and `xcntperchap` v0.4 packages for this. (The recent updates of `xparse` and L3 kernel packages required a small code change in both packages.)

Here is link to get to older versions of both packages: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s6apfkrga0qk92e/AAA2Wbq9uVSkZ19M4M8CC4Via?dl=0

but I don't recommend to go back to versions `v1.1` or older for `xassoccnt`  and `v0.2` (or older) for `xcntperchap` for compatibility reasons.

**Edit** According to the O.P. v1.3 (`xassoccnt`) and v0.3 (`xcntperchap`) work with older releases of `xparse` (pre to 2017/04/01).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcntperchap}% Loads xassoccnt as well!

\RegisterTrackCounter{chapter}{page}
\newcommand\pagesexpected[1]{\ObtainTrackedValueExp{chapter}{page} of #1 pages written}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo bar}
\pagesexpected{5}

\blindtext[20]

\chapter{Foo bar stuff}
\pagesexpected{5}

\blindtext[15]


\end{document}
```

Edit: The page counter needs a special treatment and I should attack this in one of the future releases of `xassoccnt` and `xcntperchap`

Comment: How have you installed xcntperchap and xassoccnt  on your system? My system does not have these packages at all by default (TeX Live 2016/dev).

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: I've uploaded them to CTAN one week ago ;-) It should work with older versions of both packages unless `xparse` and `expl3` packages are updated recently on your system too

Comment: Do you know which versions of `xparse` and `expl3` these should work with? My system complains that it does not recognise some syntax (it might be too old)

Comment: (That's after I installed them manually)

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: there's have been many updates to xparse and expl3 in the last months, I can't track all of them. You can try to update to the version from 2017/04/01 or try to obtain older releases of `xassoccnt` etc. from my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/home/LaTeXPackages/xassoccnt

Comment: The older versions work! I went back to the 29/4/2017 versions of both `xassoccnt` and `xcntperchap`.

Comment: @NathanaelFarley: I wonder a little bit about the date, but you mean v1.3 for `xassoccnt` and `v0.3` for `xcntperchap`, most likely. Happy TeXing